# Why isn't my Python request module code working and letting me auto-login into Reddit? It keeps returning 400 response

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, reddit, python-requests-html

With using the requests module, I'm trying to create an "auto-login" into my Reddit account program.
My Python code:

```
   s = requests.Session()
   url = 'https://www.reddit.com/login'
   payload = {'username':'username','password':'password'}
   response = s.post(url,data=payload)
   response.status_code
   response.content
```

'response.status_code' keeps returning 400. Why do I keep getting a 400 http response when my Chrome settings allow cookies?
Also, 'response.content' returns that I have a bad CSRF Token.

```
b'<html>\n <head>\n  <title>400 Bad CSRF Token</title>\n </head>\n <body>\n  <h1>400 Bad CSRF Token</h1>\n  Access is denied.  This server can not verify that your cross-site request forgery token belongs to your login session.  Either you supplied the wrong cross-site request forgery token or your session no longer exists.  This may be due to session timeout or because browser is not supplying the credentials required, as can happen when the browser has cookies turned off.<br/><br/>\ncheck_csrf_token(): Invalid token\n\n\n </body>\n</html>
```

This totally confuses me because I am using a Session.
I have no idea why this is going wrong, does anybody know why and how to fix this?

Comment: You're not passing a CSRF token,  this is normally given to the client when you load the login page, and you're expected to pass it along with your credentials.

Comment: CSRF tokens are generated by server to validate a client. If you send a random post request that does not contain the csrf token server will return an error. Normally CSRF tokens are saved on client side in a hidden HTML field that is sent to with form-data in post request. Check this link https://portswigger.net/web-security/csrf/tokens

Comment: That makes sense but I’m just confused because in some others peoples code Ive seen, they didn’t need to pass a CRSF token to login the website. Why is this?

Answer (score 0):

Its work for me.use requests.post url as user profile link.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:83.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/83.0"
}
def main(url):
    with requests.Session() as req:
        req.headers.update(headers)
        response = req.get(url)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'lxml')
        csrf = soup.find('div',{"class": "App m-desktop"}).find(attrs={'name':'csrf_token'}).get('value')
        payload = {'username':'username','password':'password',"csrf_token":csrf}
        username = 'username'
        login_url = f"https://www.reddit.com/user/{username}"
        data = req.get(login_url, data=payload)
        print(data.content)
        print(data.status_code)

url = 'https://www.reddit.com/login/'
main(url=url)
```